# Swift - How does one animate (pulse between opacity 0 and 1) a NSImage in the menu bar?

Tags: swift, animation, nsimage, nsstatusitem, nsstatusbar

I'm new at Swift and I can't seem to find any resource for what I'm trying to achieve. Most of what I find applies only to views.

I have a `statusBarItem`:

```
statusBarItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: CGFloat(NSStatusItem.variableLength))
```

Which has an `NSImage` as the icon:

```
let img = NSImage(named: "\(appModel.selectedImage.rawValue)")
img?.size = CGSize(width: 22, height: 22)
statusBarItem.button?.image = img
```

And I'd like to animate the icon by making it pulse/fade in-out/animate opacity.

What's the best way of achieving this?

Thank you

Comment: What happens if you use a gif animation file?

Comment: I guess that's an option if everything else fails. I'd rather not have a .gif, but thanks for suggesting that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @Walt 's answer, I could figure out the macOS equivalent:

```
    func animateMenubarIcon() {
        NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup { context in
            context.duration = 1
            self.statusBarItem?.button?.animator().alphaValue = 0
        } completionHandler: {
            NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup { context in
                context.duration = 1
                self.statusBarItem?.button?.animator().alphaValue = 1
            } completionHandler: {
                self.animateMenubarIcon()
            }
        }
    }
```

This will animate the button on a loop

Answer (score 1):

Look at the class hierarchy for what you're trying to achieve. A NSStatusBar is a NSObject, and does not know how to render. It has a NSStatusBarButton, which does. Haven't tried, but something like

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay:0, options: [.repeat], animations: {
    statusBarItem.button.opacity = 0
}, completion: {
    (value: Bool) in
statusBarItem.button.opacity = 1
})
```

Comment: How do you use `UIImage`'s `animatedImage(with:duration:)` in Cocoa?

Comment: What do I need to import to have access to `UIView`? I get "Cannot find 'UIView' in scope" 

Comment: This seems to be part of `UIKit`, which is to build iOS apps, not macOS 